# How do you read an excel file that is too big using java?

Tags: java, excel, macos, apache-poi

I'm using mac and Apache Netbeans 11.2

I want to read an excel file using java, but its rows are over 50,000, and it has almost 60 columns.
So when I read it, I have an error message saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

This is the code I used to read and print the excel file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class XlsxRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        try {
            File file = new File("/Users/gyungtaepark/Desktop/RawData.xlsx"); 
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0); 
            System.out.println("here");

            Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();  
            while (itr.hasNext()) {

                Row row = itr.next();

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();   //iterating over each column  
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:    //field that represents string cell type  
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:    //field that represents number cell type  
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                            break;
                        default:
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to read this file?

I have some columns that I don't need to read, and if I remove them, the code can read the file.

I want to know either how to read the big file or remove the columns with code without manually removing them in excel.

Comment: See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api, Or https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader.

Comment: I have used https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader. To make it memory efficient, few operations are not supported like random access of rows.